# Is it valid to use Object.defineProperties with symbols?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, symbols, defineproperty

Let's take the following code:

```
var obj = {};
var x = Symbol();
Object.defineProperties(obj, {
  [x]: {
    value: true,
    writable: true
  },
  "property2": {
    value: "Hello",
    writable: false
  }
  // etc. etc.
});
console.log(obj[x])
```

Is this valid?

With the native Object.defineproperties code we get in the console.log true.

With the polyfill of zone.js

which is of the form of :

```
  Object.defineProperties = function (obj, props) {
    Object.keys(props).forEach(function (prop) {
      Object.defineProperty(obj, prop, props[prop]);
    });
    return obj;
  };
```

we get for the same code of console.log undefined.

This is because of the Object.keys function. I googled around and did not find in any place if this should be allowed or not.

Comment: Syntactically it's valid, practically it is as any other object key is converted to a string, like `Symbol()` (that would be the exact key name in this case). If you really want to be able to key by an arbitrary object - use the ES2015 `Map()`

Comment: Uh, you're not defining a property **on** the symbol here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I googled around and did not find in any place if this should be allowed or not.

You can always check the spec, in this case [§ 19.1.2.3 Object.defineProperties(O, Properties)](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-object.defineproperties).

It uses the [`OwnPropertyKeys` internal method](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-ordinary-object-internal-methods-and-internal-slots-ownpropertykeys), which does indeed list all string and symbol keys of an object.

> This is because of the `Object.keys` function

Correct. It should be `Object.getOwnPropertyNames(props).concat(Object.getOwnPropertySymbols(props))` instead. You may want to file a bug with zone.js. I do however wonder why you'd need a polyfill for the ES5 `Object.defineProperties` function when you're working with ES6 symbols?

Comment: But the polyfill shouldn't be applied in an ES6 environment where `Object.defineProperties` is already natively defined?