# For-of Loop Default Iterator Function

Tags: javascript, iterator, prototype, generator, for-of-loop

Consider this simple generator function defined on `Object.prototype`:

```js
Object.prototype.defineProperty(Object.prototype, 'pairs', {
    enumerable: false,
    * value( ) {
        for (const key in this)
            yield [ key, this[key] ];
} });
```

Of course, it could be used like this:

```js
const object = { goats_teleported: 42 };

for (const [ key, value ] of object.pairs());
```

But I wonder if there any way to assign `pairs` function to object prototype, so it will be automaticly fired in `for-of` loop without explicit call; just like this:

```js
for (const [ key, value ] of object);
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put the generator on `Object.prototype[Symbol.iterator]`:

```js
Object.prototype[Symbol.iterator] = function* pairs() {
  for (const key in this) yield [ key, this[key] ];
};
const object = { goats_teleported: 42, foo: 'fooval' };

for (const [ k, v ] of object) {
  console.log(k, v);
}
```

Comment: I guess iterator can not be defined with `Object.defineProperty`, yes?

Comment: I don't think so, though you can use [`Object.defineProperties`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36111582/is-it-valid-to-use-object-defineproperties-with-symbols)

Answer (score 2):

```
   Object.prototoype[Symbol.iterator] = function* pairs() {
     //...
   };
```

But be aware that this could cause side effects everywhere. This shouldn't be used in production (or at least, on your own risk ;)).

Answer (score 1):

in ES6 you can use `Symbol.iterator` to define custom iterator for prototype.
See [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Symbol/iterator)